# The "Products" menu makes it hard to access other menu options when accessing see Stack Overflow on a normal-sized phone

Tags: discussion, products-menu

The "Products" menu makes it hard (need to to some horizontal scrolling) to access other menu options when accessing see Stack Overflow on a normal-sized phone: that'd be nice to move it somewhere else, as I'm guessing users click on "Products" less often than they do on the top-rightmost menu items. Also, this makes the user experience inconsistent between different Stack Exchange websites, as other Stack Exchange websites don't have the "features" option in the menu.

[image]

Comment: another unnerving something or other, i ignored it, but you are right, it makes it harder

Comment: "I'm guessing users click on "Products" less often than they do on the top-rightmost menu items." Well, I've never clicked it on purpose, so...